# How to get location from firebase using geofire

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I am using Geofire to get current location and save it in firebase. But id don't know how to retrieve it from firebase. I have tried various codes available on StackOverflow ,but I am not able to retrieve it and put a marker on it. Please help me with exact code.

```js
public class LocationMapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    private DatabaseReference ref;
    private FirebaseUser user;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    Boolean isLoggingOut=false;
    Button logout1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_maps);
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LocationMapsActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);

        }
        else {

            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }


       /* logout1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);
        logout1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                isLoggingOut=true;

                disconnectServiceProvider();
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                Intent intent=new Intent(ServiceProviderMapActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return;
            }
        });*/
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }
        buildGoogleApiClient();

        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        String userid=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid();
        user=firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        final DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ServiceProvidersLocations").child(user.getUid());
        final GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(dbRef);

        geoFire.getLocation("Locations",new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                LatLng locTION= new LatLng(location.latitude,location.longitude);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(locTION).title("Name")).setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

     /*   // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));*/
    }
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient(){

        mGoogleApiClient=new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLastLocation=location;
        LatLng latLng=new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker is on your current location"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(18));
        String userId=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("serviceConsumers");

        GeoFire geoFire=new GeoFire(ref);
        geoFire.setLocation(userId,new GeoLocation(mLastLocation.getLatitude(),mLastLocation.getLongitude()), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error)
            {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LocationMapsActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);

        }

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {


    }

    final int LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE=1;
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch(requestCode){
            case LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Provide Permission to use application ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
            }





        }
    }
    private void disconnectServiceProvider()
    {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        String userId=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("serviceProvidersAvailable");

        GeoFire geoFire=new GeoFire(ref);

        geoFire.removeLocation(userId);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if(!isLoggingOut)
        {
            disconnectServiceProvider();

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

[image]

Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

[Check this link,you might be able to get a way of retrieving it...](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/realtime-asset-tracking/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#5)

Comment: But I want to retrieve it from firebase